# Watch gulp http response for change

Tags: node.js, gulp, request

I want to run gulp task which requests api endpoint and watch for changes in response, after change is detected gulp will run `build` task.

To achieve it I created one task that watches file with request response body:

```
gulp.task('watch-response', function () {
    gulp.watch('response_file', function() {
        gulp.start('build');
    });
});
```

And one task that run api request, parse response body to json and saves it in file `response_file`.

```
request = require('request'),
fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('api_request', function () {
    request('www.api.com/endpoint', function(error, response, body) {
        var hash = JSON.parse(body).hash;
        fs.writeFileSync('response_file', hash);
    });
});
```

The problem here is that I want to run `api_request` task in loop with some delay, so api will be requested constantly. I tried to run it in while(true) loop but it errored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setTimeout` ,just like this, then it will works in loop with some delay:

```
   gulp.task('api_request', function () {
      var delay = 1000;
      function const_request (){
        request('www.api.com/endpoint', function(error, response, body) {
            var hash = JSON.parse(body).hash;
            fs.writeFileSync('response_file', hash);
            setTimeout(const_request, delay);
        });
      }
     const_request();
    });
```